# Is there an option to replace the vacuum seal in the main valve of a sprinkler system?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I tried blowing out my sprinkler system and the pressure blew right though the top.  I unscrewed the top dome and found that the metal seal with a rubber seal had worn away, there was a thin piece of rubber on the seal.  Unfortunately, there is metal piece across the middle of the opening, which has a downward facing spring and a metal rod in the center to hold the valve in place.  I tried cutting a tennis ball in half, but, I had to cut the tennis ball to fit around the metal rod.  It did not work and my alternative is to disassemble the unit.  Any suggestions?

Comment: This is going to need a picture.  There are many valve designs, and we can't tell what you have.

Comment: It's an Apollo Model #4050500 with a serial #CD924.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the vacuum breaker valve that prevents back-flow. They are generally required by law in sprinkler systems. In 1996 our county started requiring spring loaded types. There are many designs . If you can't find a replacement part from the manufacturer , you may need to replace the valve. If you replace the valve , the city or county may want to inspect it.

Comment: Most manufacturers have rebuild kits for them.